# Mudar valor de acordo com o digitado no input usando AJax sem clicar em um botão

Tags: php, ajax

Preciso que o ajax pegue o valor digitado no **input e mostre esse valor em uma div sem clicar em um botão**, estou utilizando o Ajax para isso, mas não está dando certo. O que eu poderia fazer para resolver?

Meu Ajax

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('input#valor').on('change',function () {
        var valor = $(this).val();

        $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "SaveDecision.php",
                 data: {valor: valor },
                 success: function(msg) {
                     $('#autosavenotify').text(msg);
                 }
      })
  });
});
```

Html para digital e receber o valor na div.

```
<input value="" type="text" class="form-control" name="valor" id="valor" placeholder="valor">

<div id="autosavenotify"></div>
```

tentei assim mas também nao funcionou

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input#valor').on('keypress',function () {
        var valor = $(this).val();

        $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "SaveDecision.php",
                 data: {valor: valor },
                 success: function(msg) {
                     $('#autosavenotify').text(msg);
                 }
      })
  });
});
```

Comment: `$('input#valor').on('keypress',function () {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input.input').keyup(function() {
    $('div.showDiv').html($(this).val());
  })
})
```

```css
input,div {
padding: 6px;
display:block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class='input' type='text'>
<div class='showDiv'></div>
```

Adaptando à sua necessidade, funcionaria na teoria assim:

1) Retornando a response de sucesso do $.ajax();

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input#valor').keyup(function() {
        var valor = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "SaveDecision.php",
                 data: {valor: valor },
                 success: function(msg) {
                     $('#autosavenotify').html(msg);
                 }
      })
  });
});
```

2) Apenas inserindo na DIV independente do response do $.ajax();

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input#valor').keyup(function() {
        var valor = $(this).val();
        $('#autosavenotify').html(valor);
        $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "SaveDecision.php",
                 data: {valor: valor },
                 success: function(msg) {
                     // $('#autosavenotify').html(msg);
                     console.log(msg);
                 }
      })
  });
});
```

Mas lembre-se, que a cada evento (tecla subindo), a função será executada, e o seu AJAX também, isso pode comprometer o desempenho da sua aplicação, visto que o  PHP executa apenas uma Thread por vez.

Comment: teria que usar o Ajax, pois vou precisar fazer um cálculo com o valor digitado no input, como ficaria?

Comment: Confere aí, no seu código, altere a referência da sua DIV, seria isso?

Comment: Trata no seu PHP o uso das chamadas do AJAX, validando se há necessidade de continuar seu código PHP, faz algumas regrinhas para evitar o consumo excessivo de recursos do servidor.

Comment: Atualizei com os dois exemplos.

Comment: funcionou, muito obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Altera o `text` para `html`

```
$('#autosavenotify').html(msg);
```

Se quiser colocar o valor em um `input` use `.val(msg)`